# How do I create a template to store my HTML file when creating a web app with Python's Flask Framework in the PyCharm IDE?

Tags: python, html, flask, pycharm

I am trying to do a tutorial through FreeCodeCamp using Python's Flask Framework to create a web app in PyCharm and I am stuck on a section where it says 'Flask looks for HTML files in a folder called template. You need to create a template folder and put all your HTML files in there.' I am confused on how to make this template folder; is it just a regular folder or are there steps to create it and drag/drop the HTML files to it? Any tips or info would be of great help!!!

Comment: Yes, just create a regular folder in the app root called 'templates' not 'template' and place your HTML files in there (i.e. index.html), by default Flask will look into that folder when rendering HTML using the render_template function (i.e.return render_template("index.html"))

Comment: @ThaerA okay yes, it is through Project Structures in the Settings right? And yup I have the render_template function! I really appreicate the help, thanks once again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the tutorial ask you, you have to create a folder call "templates" (not "template"). In PyCharm you can do this by right-clicking on the left panel and select *New I Directory*. In this folder you can then create your template files (right click on the newly created folder and select *New I File*, then enter the name of your file with the *.html* extension).

By default, flask looks in the "templates" folder to find your template when you call `render_template("index.html")`.  Notice that you don’t put the full path of your file at the first parameter but just the relative path to the "templates" folder.